# Addressbook leaks

Tags: iphone

Hello I m getting firstname, lastname and mobile number from below code

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{


    NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,

                                                   kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    firstNameLabel.text = name;

    [name release];

    NSString *lastName =(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    lastNameLabel.text = lastName;
    [lastName release];

    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones); i++) {
            if(identifier == ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex (multiPhones, i)) {
                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                 CFRelease(multiPhones);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneNumberRef;

                numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
                // [phoneNumber release];
               // CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
            }
            //CFRelease(multiPhones);
        }
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

And I am getting leaks.. Here is screen shot. Please help me to resolve leaks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code

```
if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones); i++) {
            if(identifier == ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex (multiPhones, i)) {
                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneNumberRef;

                numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
                // [phoneNumber release];
                CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
            }
        }
            CFRelease(multiPhones);

    }
```